# How to get Employee --> Manager without separate tables (pandas or SQL)?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, pandas

Is there a code to do this in pandas simply? Or perhaps I should try SQL (I am not very familiar with SQL). Here is what I have so far (fake example, the real one has about 20,000 individuals)

employee_df =

```
    EmpID   Name    Title   ManagerID
    abc123   John   Head    pqr456
    pqr456   Jake   VP      bs92999
    zyx987   Jill   Lead    abc123
    bs92999  Bob    SVP     NaN
```

Duplicate the dataframe: 
manager_df = employee_df

```
roster = pd.merge(manager_df, employee_df, how='outer', left_on ='ManagerID', right_on = 'EmpID')
```

My output is messy, although seemingly correct (it is telling me who the manager is without having separate tables by referring to itself).

```
    EmpID_x Name_x  Title_x ManagerID_x  EmpID_y Name_y Title_y ManagerID_y
    abc123  John    Head      pqr456    pqr456   Jake       VP          bs92999
    pqr456  Jake    VP        bs92999   bs92999  Bob        SVP         NaN
    zyx987  Jill    Lead      abc123    abc123   John       Head        pqr456
    bs92999 Bob     SVP       NaN       NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
    NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN       zyx987   Jill       Lead        abc123
```

The most common desired output would be:

```
EmpID | Name | Title | Manager_Name
```

But sometimes I would need another level too (the boss of the boss), with a max potential of about 5 layers which seems crazy but there is a lot of hierarchy - such high layers is not necessary all of the time but I would like to be able to roll this data up to a higher level if needed:

```
EmpID | Name | Title | Manager_Name_1 | Manager_Name_2
```

The third dataframe is reporting_df:

```
EmpID | ManagerID | StartDate | EndDate
```

Sometimes there are management changes that happen even mid-month and the results should reflect on the manager who 'owned' that employee on that date.

file = any file or report that has the EmpID where I might want to find out who the manager (or their manager) was on the date which is also included on the file. Is this the right approach to solve for this?

```
for i in range(len(file)):  
        file.ix[i,'Manager'] = reporting_df[(reporting_df.StartDate.shift(-1) > file.StartDate[i]) &(reporting_df.StartDate <= file.Date[i])]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a little tricky in parts, so let's build it in steps.  First, let's slightly rename the columns to make things easier later on (just adding '_0' to three of the columns):

```
     EmpID Name_0 Title_0 ManagerID_0
0   abc123   John    Head      pqr456
1   pqr456   Jake      VP     bs92999
2   zyx987   Jill    Lead      abc123
3  bs92999    Bob     SVP         NaN
```

Main trick here is we need a mapping, which can be done with a series:

```
df.set_index('EmpID')['Name_0']
```

The key there is we set 'EmpID' as the index, which then gives us a mapping from 'EmpID' to 'Name_0' and we could do that likewise for 'Title_0' and 'ManagerID_0'.

Try it out for one column:

```
df['ManagerID_0'].map( df.set_index('EmpID')['Name_0'] )

0    Jake
1     Bob
2    John
3     NaN
```

Now just wrap in a 'for' to get the full version:

```
for i in range(3):
    for col in ['Name_','Title_','ManagerID_']:
        df[col+str(i+1)] = df['ManagerID_'+str(i)].map( 
                                            df.set_index('EmpID')[col+'0'] )

     EmpID Name_0 Title_0 ManagerID_0 Name_1 Title_1 ManagerID_1 Name_2    
0   abc123   John    Head      pqr456   Jake      VP     bs92999    Bob   
1   pqr456   Jake      VP     bs92999    Bob     SVP         NaN    NaN   
2   zyx987   Jill    Lead      abc123   John    Head      pqr456   Jake   
3  bs92999    Bob     SVP         NaN    NaN     NaN         NaN    NaN   

  Title_2 ManagerID_2 Name_3 Title_3 ManagerID_3  
0     SVP         NaN    NaN     NaN         NaN  
1     NaN         NaN    NaN     NaN         NaN  
2      VP     bs92999    Bob     SVP         NaN  
3     NaN         NaN    NaN     NaN         NaN
```

I set range to 3 because that has 'ManagerID_3' at NaN for everyone but if you have more levels you can set that higher of course.

Comment: That worked quite well. That should be a lot more efficient than storing these columns permanently. Do you have advice on how to track management changes? I imagine it is EmpID | ManagerID | StartDate | EndDate as a separate table and then join it back somehow? Like if I look at one employee, his performance in January should be under Jake, but on Feb 15th it switches to Bob?

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand the last part of the question.  I would suggest asking a new question specifically about that and in particular provide some sample data.  You'll get better answers the more specific you can be with providing sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can make join use merge function in pandas

```py
x = new_df2[['EmpID', 'ManagerID', 'Name']].merge(new_df2[['EmpID', 'ManagerID', 'Name']],
                                            left_on='ReportsTo', right_on='EmployeeID', how='left')
x[['EmpID_x', 'Name_x', 'Name_y']].sort_values(by='Name_y') # sort by manager name

x.rename(columns={"Name_x": "Employee_Name", "Name_y": "Manager_Name"}, inplace=True)
```